# Cannot use procedure in the select statement?

Tags: plsql, procedure

Below is my code to create types and tables. It's all correct:

```
CREATE TYPE shape_typ AS OBJECT (
l   INTEGER, -- length
w   INTEGER, -- width
h   INTEGER, -- height
MEMBER FUNCTION area RETURN INTEGER,
MEMBER FUNCTION volume RETURN INTEGER,
MEMBER PROCEDURE display (SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape_typ) );

CREATE TYPE BODY shape_typ AS 
MEMBER FUNCTION volume RETURN INTEGER IS
BEGIN
   RETURN l * w * h;
-- same as previous line RETURN SELF.l * SELF.w * SELF.h; 
END;
MEMBER FUNCTION area RETURN INTEGER IS
BEGIN -- not necessary to include SELF in following
    RETURN 2 * (l * w + l * h + w * h);
END;
MEMBER PROCEDURE display (SELF IN OUT NOCOPY shape_typ) IS
  BEGIN
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Length: ' || l || ' - ' || 
                        'Width: ' || w || ' - ' ||
                        'Height: ' || h );
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Volume: ' || volume || ' - ' || 
                        'Area: ' || area );
  END;
END;

CREATE TABLE shapes (
shape       shape_typ,
create_date DATE );

INSERT INTO shapes VALUES (
shape_typ (3,3,3), '17-MAR-2008' );

INSERT INTO shapes VALUES (
shape_typ (1,8,2), '17-FEB-2008' );

INSERT INTO shapes VALUES (
shape_typ (1,1,1), '27-MAR-2008' );

SELECT s.shape.l,s.shape.w,s.shape.h,s.shape.area() FROM shapes s;

DECLARE
shap shapes%rowtype;
BEGIN -- PL/SQL block for selecting-displaying a student
  SELECT * INTO shap
    FROM shapes s 
    WHERE s.shape.l=1 and s.shape.w=1 and s.shape.h=1;
  shap.shape.display;
END;
```

However, when I try to execute the procedure in a the following statement, it gives me an error message.

```
SELECT s.shape.l,s.shape.w,s.shape.h,s.shape.display() FROM shapes s;
```

The error message is that:

> ORA-06553: PLS-222: no function with name 'DISPLAY' exists in this scope
>       06553. 00000 -  "PLS-%s: %s"
>       *Cause:
>       *Action:
>       Error at Line: 49 Column: 38

I am wondering whether it is because I cannot use the procedure in a select statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use procedures in SQL-Statements.

The procedure `DISPLAY` can only be used in a PL/SQL context.

See Oracle Documentation : [Coding PL/SQL Subprograms and Packages](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db121/ADFNS/adfns_packages.htm#ADFNS00906)

Comment: Is it because the procedure might return more than one record? But meanwhile functions only return exactly one record so that it can be used in the SQL select statement?

Comment: Because Procedures doesn't return a value (except for OUT parameters). Yes, a function returns one value (except with OUT parameters, but those can't be used in SQL, too). Thats why functions can be used in SQL.

Comment: If procedure only returns one value with OUT parameter, can it then be used in SQL?

Comment: Definetly not. In general, procedures can't be used in SQL. Your anonymous PL/SQL block looks good, why do you want to print something out in SQL? If you absolutely need an output in SQL, wrap it into a function. Not nice but feasable for dev or testing purposes only.

Comment: Got it. Thanks for your help.